# Description property not in Autodesk files response

Tags: autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

I'm calling the   [https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{projectId}/items/{itemId}/versions](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/items/%7BitemId%7D/versions) from Autodesk API and getting a result similar to the one at the end of this post.

Inside Autodesk UI every file has a description, however, I can't find this in the returned data when calling the versions endpoint. Is there another endpoint that will return this data?
[image: picture of autodesk UI]

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": ""
        }
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "type": "versions",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:jklj?version=24",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "NAME.rvt",
            "displayName": "DISPLAYNAME.rvt",
            "createTime": "2023-08-23T07:01:24.0000000Z",
            "createUserId": "{creating UserId }",
            "createUserName": "{Users Name}",
            "lastModifiedTime": "2023-08-23T07:02:01.0000000Z",
            "lastModifiedUserId": "{userId}",
            "lastModifiedUserName": "{userName}",
            "versionNumber": 24,
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
            "storageSize": 5210572272,
            "fileType": "rvt",
            "extension": {
                "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
                "version": "1.3.0",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.3.0"
                },
                "data": {
                    "modelVersion": 1574,
                    "isCompositeDesign": true,
                    "mimeType": "application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
                    "compositeParentFile": "{comname}.rvt",
                    "projectGuid": "{projectId}",
                    "originalItemUrn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:{urnId}",
                    "modelType": "multiuser",
                    "latestEpisodeGuid": "{Id}",
                    "modelGuid": "{id}",
                    "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                    "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
                    "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
                    "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
                    "revisionDisplayLabel": "24",
                    "sourceFileName": "{fileNmae}.rvt",
                    "conformingStatus": "NONE"
                }
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": ""
            },
            "webView": {
                "href": ""
            }
        },
        "relationships": {
            "item": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "items",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "refs": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": ""
                    },
                    "related": {
                        "href": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "downloadFormats": {
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "derivatives": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "derivatives",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "meta": {
                    "link": {
                        "href": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "thumbnails": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "thumbnails",
                    "id": ""
                },
                "meta": {
                    "link": {
                        "href": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            "storage": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "objects",
                    "id": "{urn}.rvt"
                },
                "meta": {
                    "link": {
                        "href": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    ]
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it is still a wish in the list (wish Id= FDM-3124). Sorry for the bad news.   We are pushing engineer team to implement. your patience and understanding are highly appreciated